# How to test toast messages in Protractor in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, toastr

In the app I am testing, there are lines in the component class that displays a toastr message. I am trying to write a protractor test that tests to if these messages display or not but am having a hard time. The reason being that I have no mention of the toastr in my Html, so I do not really have an idea of how to have protractor find it. Here is the code where I use toastr. I want to test if the success message displays if the user registers or updates.

```
     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.success === "success") {
            this.toastr.success(result.isToEdit == true ? "User is updated successfully " : "User is created successfully.");
            this.getUsers();
        }
    });
```

I am scratching my head at this one. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Edit: I believe I have solved this problem. I did the following code to access the message:

```
return element(by.css('.toast-message'))
```

Comment: Which `toastr` library are you using?

Comment: In the module file I have: import { ToastModule } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does exist in the HTML, but only when it's visible.

In the configuration, you can specify a class on the message, by setting `messageClass`

Then you can search for it using the CSS class:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr#toastoptions-configurations

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to wait for toaster to apeear.
Add `browser.sleep(1000)` to wait for it. Its the simplest and not really correct solution, but as first step you can try it out.
The better solution is to use `await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element), 1000, element.locator());` to let protractor wait for element to appear for *at most 1000 miliseconds*, not blocking the whole test for sleeping

Comment: Thank you for the insight. My main issue is retrieving the toast message. I am not sure how to access the message when it is not anywhere in my html. The only mention of it is in the code I have in the question. Any idea how I can retrive it in my object class? Thanks!

Comment: you can use selectors by class, for example, or by xpath. Find out some unique selector an use it. If some specific class or id can be passed to toast, you better use it.

Comment: Thank you, I think i figured it out. toast-message seemed to work!

Comment: @KidA2001 could you please share, how did you resolve this issue. I am facing the same